# Trucrypt and Veracrypt stopped working after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, encryption, veracrypt

I have several file folders that I have encrypted with Trucrypt or Veracrypt.  These have worked flawlessly for many years on several operating systems including Ubuntu.  After upgrading several Ubuntu desktops to 22.04 I noticed that I am no longer able to unlock these folders.  I get a bad file descriptor error message after entering the correct passphrases.

Not much information out there about this.  I did find a thread elsewhere complaining about this same problem and the solution was to start Trucrypt or Veracrypt from the shell with the command:

```
sudo veracrypt &
```

This works fine but is not nearly as elegant as using the GUI interface that has worked perfectly for a great many years.

Is there some way to get these apps to work correctly again from the usual logged in mortal user GUI launch method?

Trucrypt has long been depreciated and is not part of the Ubuntu distribution.  Veracrypt was installed and is maintained using the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unit193/encryption
```

Zulucrypt is a helpful workaround but it is confusing to use, does not unlock some of my files and is missing features like display/cache passphrase that are important to me.  What would be better would be getting these apps to work correctly as they have for years.

NOTE:  I added veracrypt (currently at the lasted version 1.25.9) because Trucrypt (which is what I have been using for eons) has been long depreciated and is unsupported.  So I didn't want this question to get blown off for asking about unsupported software.  Veracrypt works/worked fine on files encrypted by Trucrypt and is a currently supported app.  Trucrypt and Veracrypt fail in the same way with the same error message and the workaround of running each in a shell with sudo privileges works for both.

My fundamental question is this: Trucrypt and veracrypt have worked fine for years.  Why, ever since the 22.04 upgrade, do these tools (which were at the same version level before the Ubuntu upgrade as they now are after the upgrade) have to be run from a sudo shell to work correctly?  And what can be done to just launch them from the user favorites GUI and have them work as they always have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm on 22.04 and have no trouble using VeraCrypt as [downloaded from the official site](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html).

Comment: The site you refer to is also considered an untrusted third party source and there is no update capability following your advice.  Since others are having this same problem your input is unresponsive.  Worked prior to 22.04.  Doesn't work now.

Comment: Incorrect.  The owner (unit193) lists:-apt-repository ppa:unit193/test so I'm assuming /encryption is for fully tested and released versions.  Your assumption that I am dealing with "buggy" software has no basis in fact.  If you believe that the answer to my question is that I am working with buggy software please state your evidence for that opinion.  I asked a very simple question:  worked prior to upgrading.  Doesn't work now.  Why, since the 22.04 upgrade, does it have to be run from a sudo shell to work correctly?

Comment: If the problem were either Ubuntu 22.04 or Veracrypt, it wouldn't work on my system. And as far as the Web site of the developer being "untrusted", you failed to say **who**, specifically, doesn't trust the developers of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZuluCrypt is a current, fully supported, 100% compatible replacement for TruCrypt.  It took a fair amount of research and testing but all of my volumes that were initially created on various operating systems using TruCrypt are fully usable on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with ZuluCrypt.